# Trying to make a function with multiple commands into a single alias in powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, alias, powershell-3.0

Here's the code and the error I get:

```cs
function CSheridanStruct {
    New-Item -Path "C:\Users\Admininistrator\" -Name "Sheridan" -ItemType "directory" |
        New-Item -Path "C:\Users\Admininistrators\Sheridan\" -ItemType "directory" -Name "SYST23551", "Notes"
}

Set-Alias Sheridan CSheridanStruct

Sheridan
```

```
New-Item : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' 
required by parameter 'Name'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:2 char:167
+ ... rators\Sheridan\" -ItemType "directory" -Name "SYST23551", "Notes" }
+                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

I also tried it without the pipline on separate lines (this is within the function) tried just `Set-Alias Sheridan CSheridanStruct` same errors.
And I tried to do `Set-Alias -Name "Sheridan" -Value CSheridanStruct`.
Same output. The functions commands within, I've already checked and work and have created the directories. I just need to set an alias for all the commands to launch at once with typing the alias Sheridan in PowerShell..

Comment: Your problem is unrelated to your alias definition, which work fine and does succeed in invoking your function. It is your function that is broken: `New-Item`'s `-Name` parameter is not designed to accept _arrays_ of strings, only a _single_ string.

Comment: Also, pipelining `New-Item` like you do in your function doesn't make any sense, because you're not using the output of the first command as the input for the second anyway.

Comment: Adding to the above:  you don't need separate New-Item lines for subfolders, ie:

New-Item -Path "C:\Users\Admininistrators\Sheridan\SYST23551" -ItemType "directory"

would create both folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue you are having is trying to put a array in the **new-item -name** field

```powershell
New-Item -Path "C:\Users\Admininistrators\Sheridan\" -ItemType "directory" -Name "SYST23551", "Notes"
```

The error you are getting is because of **-Name "SYST23551", "Notes"**

Second there is no need to pipe these commands as they have nothing to do with each other

Here is a working version of your script

```
function CSheridanStruct {
    New-Item -Path "C:\Users\Admininistrator\" -Name "Sheridan" -ItemType "directory"
    New-Item -Path "C:\Users\Admininistrator\Sheridan" -Name "SYST23551" -ItemType "directory"
    New-Item -Path "C:\Users\Admininistrator\Sheridan" -Name "Notes" -ItemType "directory"
}

Set-Alias Sheridan CSheridanStruct

Sheridan
```

Comment: thank you all for the advice and the thank you ArcSet for the full presentation of the code. much appreciated new to powershell will be asking quite a few questions on here... didn't know a CLI could do soo much and actually create methods functions basically it's own language. PowerShell is definitely POWERful and is the next new thing!